# R: update plot [xy]lims with new points() or lines() additions?

Tags: r, plot

***Background:***

I'm running a Monte Carlo simulation to show that a particular process (a cumulative mean) does **not** converge over time, and often diverges wildly in simulation (the expectation of the random variable = infinity).  I want to plot about 10 of these simulations on a line chart, where the x axis has the iteration number, and the y axis has the cumulative mean up to that point.

***Here's my problem:***

I'll run the first simulation (each sim. having 10,000 iterations), and build the main plot based on its current range.  But often one of the simulations will have a range a few orders of magnitude large than the first one, so the plot flies outside of the original range.  So, **is there any way to dynamically update the ylim or xlim of a plot upon adding a new set of points or lines?**

I can think of two **workarounds** for this: 1. store each simulation, then pick the one with the largest range, and build the base graph off of that (not elegant, and I'd have to store a lot of data in memory, but would probably be laptop-friendly **[[EDIT: as Marek points out, this is not a memory-intense example, but if you know of a nice solution that'd support far more iterations such that it becomes an issue (think high dimensional walks that require much, much larger MC samples for convergence) then jump right in]]**) 2. find a seed that appears to build a nice looking version of it, and set the ylim manually, which would make the demonstration reproducible.

Naturally I'm holding out for something more elegant than my workarounds.  Hoping this isn't too pedestrian a problem, since I imagine it's not uncommon with simulations in R.  Any ideas?

Comment: I just wonder: have you any memory issues? 10 vectors of 10.000 isn't a lot. As I check: X<-lapply(1:10,function(i) rnorm(100000,0,1000)); object.size(X)/1024/1024 is just 7MB of RAM. So 1. should be ok.

Comment: No, good point - I'm definitely NOT running into memory issues (hence laptop-friendly) with this simulation, but I'll be demonstrating far more complicated [Q]MC[MC] simulations in the future, with the same output of a graph.  I'm looking for something that in general wouldn't rely on too much storage, especially as things get more complicated and I need far larger MC sample sizes to ensure convergence.  This may be unavoidable / I might be overestimating the difficulty of implementing said future simulations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is possible using base graphics, if someone has a solution I'd love to see it.  However graphics systems based on grid (lattice and ggplot2) allow the graphics object to be saved and updated.  It's insanely easy in ggplot2.

`require(ggplot2)`

make some data and get the range:

```
foo <- as.data.frame(cbind(data=rnorm(100), numb=seq_len(100)))
```

make an initial ggplot object and plot it:

```
p <- ggplot(as.data.frame(foo), aes(numb, data)) + layer(geom='line')
p
```

make some more data and add it to the plot

```
foo <- as.data.frame(cbind(data=rnorm(200), numb=seq_len(200)))

p <- p + geom_line(aes(numb, data, colour="red"), data=as.data.frame(foo))
```

plot the new object

```
p
```

Comment: This is a good solution, and proof I need to use ggplot2 more. Using rnorm(200, 0, 1000) in the second foo assignment really shows that this works beautifully :-)

Comment: Now that I think about this a bit more, this won't help w/ a memory issue if there is one (all that ggplot object data has to live somewhere.)

Comment: Given this particular context (simple, short simulations), using ggplot is the nicest approach.  And the fact is, ggplot2 is really nice for other reasons, so an answer that uses it is all right in my book.  I'll potentially ask this again if . when memory IS an issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think (1) is the best option. I actually don't think this *isn't* elegant. I think it would be more computationally intensive to redraw every time you hit a point greater than xlim or ylim.

Also, I saw in Peter Hoff's book about Bayesian statistics a cool use of ts() instead of lines() for cumulative sums/means. It looks pretty spiffy:

[image]

Comment: A solution that uses base graphics and is memory lighter would be to track the X and Y max.  Then save the full data set to a file.  When you complete a new run, if the range is larger redo the plot and then loop through the stored data files.

Comment: Instead of check (and eventually replot) after each trial, one could save data and store ranges, then find global range, use it as ylim and plot results (for the first time).

Comment: Part of my backing of this approach was Marek's comment above, that this isn't *that* much data. 7MB of RAM. Compared to the genome assembly memory requirements I've seen recently, MCMC sims are a drop in the bucket!

Comment: Yep - this example doesn't require me to worry about memory, even on a crappy laptop.  Let's see what y'all say when I bring in a far bigger fish :)